# Python 3.7 text-to-speech only playing one audio file, sometimes no audio at all, using IDLE editor

Tags: audio, text-to-speech, python-3.7

I am using the IDLE editor and Python 3.7, and I would like to know why my code is not playing multiple audio files (sequentially) and sometimes not playing audio at all:

```
import re
import wave
import pyaudio
import _thread
import time

class TextToSpeech:

    CHUNK = 1024

    def __init__(self, words_pron_dict:str = 'cmudict-0.7b.txt'):
        self._l = {}
        self._load_words(words_pron_dict)

    def _load_words(self, words_pron_dict:str):
        with open(words_pron_dict, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                if not line.startswith(';;;'):
                    key, val = line.split('  ',2)
                    self._l[key] = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+",val)

    def get_pronunciation(self, str_input):
        list_pron = []
        for word in re.findall(r"[\w']+",str_input.upper()):
            if word in self._l:
                list_pron += self._l[word]
        print(list_pron)
        delay=0
        for pron in list_pron:
            _thread.start_new_thread( TextToSpeech._play_audio, (pron,delay,))
            delay += 0.145


def _play_audio(sound, delay):
    try:
        time.sleep(delay)
        wf = wave.open("sounds/"+sound+".wav", 'rb')
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                        channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                        rate=wf.getframerate(),
                        output=True)

        data = wf.readframes(TextToSpeech.CHUNK)

        while data:
            stream.write(data)
            data = wf.readframes(TextToSpeech.CHUNK)

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

        p.terminate()
        return
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tts = TextToSpeech()
    while True:
        tts.get_pronunciation(input('Enter a word or phrase: '))
```

I have a list of audio files that will play in a certain order, depending on what word I type in, when running the code. The code has no errors, but when I run it, when I type in a word, it only plays the first audio file needed (Example: When I type in "buy" it requires these two sounds: "b" and "ie" played together), but it only plays the first sound, "b", and sometimes no sound at all.

Why isn't it playing multiple audio files? I know that lots of people have been having this issue, but haven't been able to solve it.
Thank you for your help in advance, it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you want them played sequentially, why starting threads? More interestingly, why using low-level API? That's asking for trouble - which you have already found out :).

Comment: The editor should not affect code execution.  Check to make sure that my indentation fixes are correct.